# Computing $0.0625^{-2.25}$ without a calculator

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, decimal-expansion

It is quite easy to see that $0.0625^{-2.25} = 512$ by plugging this into a calculator.

Of course, mathematics existed for millennia before the invention of the calculator; is there a way to compute $0.0625^{-2.25}$ *without* resorting to calculator usage?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! You would be better received here if it were more clear that you put an honest effort into this question. You say you know the answer. What is it? And what don't you like about it? When you tried to look up how this is done, what problems did you encounter? If you edit your question well, I'm sure that it will be reopened.

Comment: No I mean I know the answer by calculator, not by method.

Answer (score 4):

A physicist would just try out these things with [log tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_logarithm) and if he's old would use a [slide rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slide_rule),
$$y = 0.0625^{-2.25}\\
\begin{align}
\implies\log_{10}(y) &= -2.25\cdot\log(6.25 \times10^{-2})\\
&= -2.25 \cdot \left(\log_{10}(6.25) -2\right)\\
&\approx -2.25 \cdot(0.79588 -2)\\
&= 2.70927
\end{align}\\
\therefore\space y = 10^{2.70927} \approx 512
$$

Answer (score 3):

0.0625^(-2.25) is $\frac{1}{16}$ raised to the $-\frac{9}{4}$. power. Now $\frac{1}{16}$ is $2^{-4}$, so $(2^{-4})^{-\frac{9}{4}}$ is the same as $2^{-4 \dot -\frac{9}{4}}$ which is $2^9$.

This site is a good reference for fractional exponentiation: http://www.purplemath.com/modules/exponent5.htm

Answer (score 2):

$0.0625^{-2.25} = \frac{1}{16}^{-\frac{9}{4}} = 16^{\frac{9}{4}} = (2^4)^{\frac{9}{4}} = 2^9 = 512$

Answer (score 2):

For these kinds of problems, it helps to be able to recognize decimal representation of common fractions.  Or, if you don't know the fraction immediately, at least know that you should calculate what the fraction is.

If $0.25$ and $0.0625$ don't jump out at you as $1/4$ and $1/16$ then you might spend a little time acquainting yourself with some of these.  Then, it's a matter of knowing rules for exponentiation, which the others have shown for you.